# printing code-generated text in margin of r markdown tufte handout

Tags: r, r-markdown, tufte

I am trying to put a margin note in my Tufte Latex document that is partially generated by r code, but have been unsuccessful. Code blocks set to print in the margin only seem to put plots there, not text or tables. Margin notes called with `tufte::marginfigure()` throw an error if they have inline code in them. And margin figure blocks ignore inline code. I have been successful getting my code-generated text to print in the margin with a footnote, but then I get footnote numbering, which I don't want. I thought of turning off numbering on that footnote, but haven't been able to.

Here's an example:

````
---
title: "Tufte Test"
author: "Neal"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  tufte::tufte_handout: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tufte)
library(tidyverse)
```

Here is some normal text with inline code: 2+3=`r 2+3`  

\vspace{10pt}
```{r block, fig.margin=TRUE, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cat('Here is a margin code block with code-generated text and a plot.')
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
cat('The text stays in the main body.')
```


\vspace{10pt}
I can combine text and code in a footnote^[2+3=`r 2+3` \newline\vspace{10pt}], but I get footnote numbering, which I don't want.

```{marginfigure, echo=TRUE}
Here is a margin figure with inline code that doesn't work: 2+3=`r 2+3` \newline\vspace{10pt}
```


`r tufte::margin_note('This is a margin note. If I try to include inline code in it, I get an error because it "failed to tidy R code in chunk"')`
````

And the output: [tufte-test.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJGId.png)

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code chunk labelled `marginfigure` just wraps the contents in the LaTeX environment called `marginfigure`.  You can do that yourself, and then the inline code will be processed properly.

That is, you replace this:

````
```{marginfigure, echo=TRUE}
Here is a margin figure with inline code that doesn't work: 2+3=`r 2+3` \newline\vspace{10pt}
```
````

with this:

```
\begin{marginfigure}
Here is a margin figure with inline code that *does* work: 2+3=`r 2+3` \newline\vspace{10pt}
\end{marginfigure}
```

Your first example is a bit more complicated.  It needs to be broken into three parts:

````
\begin{marginfigure}
`r 'Here is a margin code block with code-generated text.'`
\end{marginfigure}

```{r block, fig.margin=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
```

\begin{marginfigure}
`r 'The text doesn\'t stay in the main body.'`
\end{marginfigure}
````

You asked for PDF output, but just for the sake of completeness, if you were using `tufte::tufte_html` for HTML output instead, the equivalent result would be obtained using

```
<span class="marginnote">
Here is a margin figure with inline code that *does* work: 2+3=`r 2+3`
</span>
```